# Elasticsearch main ERROR RollingFileManager (C:\Program Files\Elastic\Elasticsearch\6.4.0\logs\elasticsearch.log)

Tags: elasticsearch, filenotfoundexception

About three days ago my local Elasticsearch instalation on Win 10 worked without any problems. Today as I tried to run elasticsearch it throws me this error. I dont understand what it means cause as you can see on the screenshot below log file exists. Why ES says java.io.FileNotFoundException? What it means and what should I do with it? Thanks a lot.

Here is console log

```
C:\Program Files\Elastic\Elasticsearch\6.4.0\bin
λ elasticsearch
2020-04-20 10:02:20,046 main ERROR RollingFileManager (C:\Program Files\Elastic\Elasticsearch\6.4.0\logs\elasticsearch.log) java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Program Files\Elastic\Elasticsearch\6.4.0\logs\elasticsearch.log (Access is denied) java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Program Files\Elastic\Elasticsearch\6.4.0\logs\elasticsearch.log (Access is denied)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:270)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:213)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:133)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.RollingFileManager$RollingFileManagerFactory.createManager(RollingFileManager.java:640)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.RollingFileManager$RollingFileManagerFactory.createManager(RollingFileManager.java:608)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.AbstractManager.getManager(AbstractManager.java:113)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.OutputStreamManager.getManager(OutputStreamManager.java:114)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.RollingFileManager.getFileManager(RollingFileManager.java:188)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.RollingFileAppender$Builder.build(RollingFileAppender.java:145)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.RollingFileAppender$Builder.build(RollingFileAppender.java:61)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.util.PluginBuilder.build(PluginBuilder.java:123)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createPluginObject(AbstractConfiguration.java:959)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createConfiguration(AbstractConfiguration.java:899)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createConfiguration(AbstractConfiguration.java:891)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.doConfigure(AbstractConfiguration.java:514)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.initialize(AbstractConfiguration.java:238)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.start(AbstractConfiguration.java:250)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.setConfiguration(LoggerContext.java:547)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.start(LoggerContext.java:263)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.logging.LogConfigurator.configure(LogConfigurator.java:163)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.logging.LogConfigurator.configure(LogConfigurator.java:119)
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.init(Bootstrap.java:294)
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.init(Elasticsearch.java:136)
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.execute(Elasticsearch.java:127)
        at org.elasticsearch.cli.EnvironmentAwareCommand.execute(EnvironmentAwareCommand.java:86)
        at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.mainWithoutErrorHandling(Command.java:124)
        at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.main(Command.java:90)
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:93)
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:86)

[org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.RollingFileManager$RollingFileManagerFactory@3e84448c] unable to create manager for [C:\Program Files\Elastic\Elasticsearch\6.4.0\logs\elasticsearch.log] with data [org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.RollingFileManager$FactoryData@4a7f959b[pattern=C:\Program Files\Elastic\Elasticsearch\6.4.0\logs\elasticsearch-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}-%i.log.gz, append=true, bufferedIO=true, bufferSize=8192, policy=CompositeTriggeringPolicy(policies=[TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy(nextRolloverMillis=0, interval=1, modulate=true), SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy(size=134217728)]), strategy=DefaultRolloverStrategy(min=-2147483648, max=2147483647, useMax=false), advertiseURI=null, layout=[%d{ISO8601}][%-5p ][%-25c{1.}                ] [] %marker%.-10000m%n, filePermissions=null, fileOwner=null]] java.lang.IllegalStateException: ManagerFactory [org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.RollingFileManager$RollingFileManagerFactory@3e84448c] unable to create manager for [C:\Program Files\Elastic\Elasticsearch\6.4.0\logs\elasticsearch.log] with data [org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.RollingFileManager$FactoryData@4a7f959b[pattern=C:\Program Files\Elastic\Elasticsearch\6.4.0\logs\elasticsearch-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}-%i.log.gz, append=true, bufferedIO=true, bufferSize=8192, policy=CompositeTriggeringPolicy(policies=[TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy(nextRolloverMillis=0, interval=1, modulate=true), SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy(size=134217728)]), strategy=DefaultRolloverStrategy(min=-2147483648, max=2147483647, useMax=false), advertiseURI=null, layout=[%d{ISO8601}][%-5p][%-25c{1.}] %marker%.-10000m%n, filePermissions=null, fileOwner=null]]
```

[image]

Comment: Oh I am sorry console has to run in admin mode. That's the reason.

Comment: I just mentioned this in my answer :p :) that it was a permission issue :D

Comment: Can you tell me where should I search directory for custom stopwords file if you are an es ninja?  I have a this stop words definition but I am not able to find that file: `"stopwords_path": "stopwords/slovak.txt"`

Comment: sorry missed this by few minutes and gave the answer on the question you asked :) and btw glad it was useful and thanks for marking the answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looks like you changed the ownership of your elasticsearch folder or now running it with a different user which doesn't have permission to write to you elasticsearch log file as clearly mentioned in the error message.

> C:\Program Files\Elastic\Elasticsearch\6.4.0\logs\elasticsearch.log
>   (Access is denied)

**Please make sure that user which is running your elasticsearch process has access to this location** `C:\Program Files\Elastic\Elasticsearch\6.4.0\logs\`.